# How exception occurred in debug mode do end execution of program buffer in RISCV architecture?

Tags: cpu-architecture, privileges, riscv

The below quotation is taken from [riscv-debug-spec version 0.132](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/riscv-debug-release.pdf).

> 3. Exceptions don’t update any registers. That includes cause, epc, tval, dpc, and mstatus.
>    They do end execution of the Program Buffer.

I understand the exceptions do not update the mentioned CSRs. However, I couldn't understand how it does end the program buffer. It is not clearly defined. Should I count the exception as dret instruction in debug mode? or should I send the exception information to the Debug Module that will take care of ending the execution buffer?

Comment: This is a very esoteric question.  Are you creating an eternal debugger?  Are you using the Program Buffer?

Comment: Thank you for your response. There are 4 privilege levels on the RISC-V architecture and one additional level called debug mode. I wanted to implement only the debug mode not the debug module or program buffer. The debug module is a different module and the program buffer sits in the memory region that debug mode reaches(as I know). Those are the parts that I have. What I don't have is the core features of debug mode. I mean dcsr, dpc... and debug mode control flow. One of the specifications of control flow is the 3rd matter that I stated above.

Comment: The issue is, I don't understand why you would CARE about this.  Are you trying to implement an ARM architecture processor from scratch?  If not, I don't see how this point would affect your life in any way.  Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: Yes I see. I am implementing it in a RISCV- OoO core. I am reading the spec and in order projects written with verilog or system verilog. However, I couldn't understand the part that I mentioned.

Comment: Ah, in that case I am out of my depth and am going to back out.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use progbuf to access memory or register.After you execute the instructions stored in progbuf, you need to end the progbuf run.With progbuf operations, programs must end with the instruction ebreak, which terminates the execution of the program buffer.
Ebreak is an instruction, encoded 0x100073, that interrupts the operation of a program so that the system can hand over the use to the Debugger.
By the way, executing the dret instruction in the program buffer results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, my question is about how an exception ends the program buffer as architecture. The matter that I stated above tells us that if there is an exception while in the debug mode it is not counted as an exception but ends the program buffer. However, it is not stated how it ends. My question is more about that point.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're trying to make.  If there's an exception, it stops reading from the program buffer.  There's nothing you have to do.

Comment: I see what you're trying to say.  One thing you need to know when discussing this is that the only exception is ebreak, which ends execution of the ProgramBuffer when executed.I understand that the exception here refers only to ebreak, and since it is ebreak, executing it will end the progbuf run.If you want to know what the core does with ebreak, I think it needs to focus more on the core side of the processing than on the debug system itself

Comment: @YangDing As I understand you, you are telling If there is an exception like illegal_instruction_exception, core should behave as ebreak_exception to end program_buffer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @TimRoberts sorry for my weak phrasing. I mean that the core has jump instruction to call and return. branch to change instruction flow. an interrupt pin to trigger and jump interrupt and debug pin to trigger and jump debug mode. As I know there is no any other architectural pins and ways to end a program flow.

Comment: Illegal instructions can cause the program to fleet, and the core can use ebreak as a way to end progbuf processing in this scenario. I don't think there are strict requirements on how to deal with illegal instructions.

Comment: @ÖmerGÜZEL   There are no strict rules on how to handle exceptions, but I can give you an example.Written by hart when it encounters an exception in debug mode. Sets abstracts.cmderr to "exception".

Comment: @YangDing You say "There are no strict rules on how to handle exceptions" however, in section 4.1, the 3rd matter there is a rule I mentioned in the post. It taught me that there is a strict rule.

Comment: @ÖmerGÜZEL I mean there are no hard and fast rules about how to implement this behavior.You can implement this function to end progbuf in any way you want when you encounter an exception.If you use progbuf to execute illegal commands, you can set a trigger condition, such as executing ebreak to enter debug mode. Also set cmderr if an exception occurs while executing the abstract comannd instruction.